# I can't use online scripts if I download them

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know what's happening here but it seems that I can't get the scripts activated if I add them to my ftp. They seem to work only when the source is online.

Here are the original scripts:

```
  <script src='http://codepen.io/assets/libs/fullpage/jquery.js'></script>
  <script src='http://labs.voronianski.com/media/js/jquery.avgrund.js'></script>
```

And here is the code for my downloaded scripts:

```
<script src="js/jquery.avgrund.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

And there is already a `<script src="js/index.js"></script>` but no other scripts are in the JS folder.

So what's going on? It's not the first time that I am doing this :/ They should work :/

Comment: What URL are you trying to include your scripts on? Is it the homepage or a page nested within a directory?

Comment: Any errors in the console? Like `404 not found`?

Comment: What does `I can't use` mean? Can you access them on that path? Does you browser give you any error messages? Etc

Comment: Everything is right guys. The js folder is relative to the html file. The syntax is correct. Even in developer source it shows the scripts. It just doesn't run.

Comment: You have your scripts in the wrong order, `jquery.js` should be first or you will get an `$ is undefined` error.

Comment: @Ricky: Is there an error on the JavaScript console?  Define "it just doesn't run".  (If nothing is executing at all then JavaScript is disabled in the browser.)  When you debug this, where/how specifically does it fail?  Can you provide a live example we can see?

Comment: Thanks @wf4 I didn't knew that the order was so important in this case.

Answer (score 3):

The reason that you are having this problem is because you have your scripts in the wrong order, `jquery.js` should be first or you will get an `$ is undefined` error.

The reason that you have to include `jquery.js` first is because your additional scripts will be written in jQuery. If you have not yet loaded jQuery, the browser will not know what to do with them.

Comment: Thanks. Importance of putting jquery first wasn't clear to me until today. :)

Answer (score 2):

The scripts seemed to be in the wrong order (which I didn't knew that was so important in this case).

`<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>`  should go first